# Solving $Ax= b$ for $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

I tried to solve this problem for A using the linearity of matrices, but I'm going nowhere. Can someone help-me with this question? Solve or give me a hint?

Thanks!

\begin{matrix}
 A \begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\
-2\\
-1\\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
-3 \\
-3 \\
-6\\
\end{bmatrix},\\ \\
\end{matrix}
\begin{matrix}
 A \begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\
0\\
7\\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
2 \\
0 \\
0\\
\end{bmatrix},\\ \\
\end{matrix}
\begin{matrix}
 A \begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\
-4\\
2\\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
-2 \\
-1 \\
-2\\
\end{bmatrix},\\ \\
\end{matrix}

Comment: I think u can do this just by taking three equations into one

Answer (score 2):

Guide:

If you have $$AB=C$$

and $B$ is invertible, then we have $$A=CB^{-1}$$

Try to construct the matrix $B$ and $C$.

---

Note that $$AB=C$$

is just $$B^TA^T=C^T$$

You can perform row operations to solve for $A^T$.

Comment: I have to construct B with all x vectors and C with all b points, right ?

Comment: yes, that's right